# TypeScript - How do you infer a class generic type from a method's parameter?

Tags: typescript, class, generics

I am trying to type a class generic from a method argument that will be called later. The generic type of the class would not be known until we called a method taking a generic argument. Then, for any other methods, the generic type would be passed on.

Honestly, for me, this seems so complex of functionality that I am not even sure TypeScript has a way of doing it...

Here's what I would like the behavior to look like:

```
class Class<T> {
    foo = (bar: T[]) => {
        /* ... */
        return this;
    };

    baz = (cb: (qux: T) => void) => {
        /* ... */
        return this;
    };
}

new Class() // Here, T should be unknown
    .foo([{ name: "John", id: "123" }]) // Here, it should be infered that T is { name: string, id: string }
    .baz((person) => null) // Here, person should have the type { name: string, id: string }
```

In this example, when we instantiate the `Class`, `T` should be unknown. Then, when we pass an array of objects to `foo`, the `T` should be inferred to be of that object type, since `bar` is typed `T[]`. Now that `T` has been infered, `qux` should be automatically typed when passing a function to `baz`. ( `baz(cb: ({ name: string, id: string }) => void)` )

Note that I do not want to have to pass a generic to the `Class` as I want it to be inferred later. In other words, I **don't** want to do

```
new Class<{ name: string, id: string }>()
```

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess writing the question acted as rubber duck debugging! About a few minutes after my post, I found this. However, it is not too pretty, so I am going to leave the thread open for a while in case a better idea comes up:

```
class Class<T> {
    foo = <U extends T>(bar: U[]) => {
        /* ... */
        return (this as unknown) as Class<U>; // not pretty
    };

    baz = <U extends T>(cb: (qux: U) => void) => {
        /* ... */
        return (this as unknown) as Class<U>; // not pretty
    };
}

new Class() // Here, T is unknown, as it should be
    .foo([{ name: "John", id: "123" }]) // Here, T becomes U ({name: string, id: string})
    .baz((person) => null); // Here, person is typed {name: string, id: string} Yay!

// This also works!
new Class() // Here, T is unknown, as it should be
    .baz((person: { name: string; id: string }) => null) // Here, T becomes U ({name: string, id: string})
    .foo([{ name: "John", id: "123" }]); // Here, bar is typed { name: string, id: string }[] Yay again!
```

By typing the methods with another generic type that extends the class' generic type, we can return `this` and "safely" type it as `Class<U>`, which now gives an actual type instead of `unknown`.

The problem here is that this only works because we are returning `this` while typing it with a new type `Class<U>`. Thus, passing an object to a method that does not return `this` would not modify it's generic type...

```
class Class<T> {
    public data: T;

    quux = <U extends T>(quuz: U) => {
        this.data = quuz;
        /* ... void */
    };
}

const c = new Class();
c.quux({ name: "John", id: "123" });
c.data // still unknown
```