# How to create a custom Svelte store with a type inferred from a method argument and without destroying it every time a reactive variable change?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm using this simple code to create a custom store:

- App.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { useStore } from "./store";

  interface Player {
    name: string;
  }

    const player = {
        name: "Bob"
    };
    
    const handleChange = () => {
        player.name = player.name === "Bob" ? "John" : "Bob"
    }
    
    const game = useStore<Player>();

    $: game.changePlayer(player);
</script>

<button on:click={handleChange}>
    Change player
</button>

{JSON.stringify($game)}
```

- store.ts:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export function useStore<T>() {
  const store = writable<T>();
    
    const changePlayer = (player: Player): void => {
        store.set({...player});
    }
    
  return {
        subscribe: store.subscribe,
        changePlayer
    };
}
```

As you can see I'm creating a new store using:

```
const game = useStore<Player>();
```

Is there a way to create a "generic" store without specify its content type at start but only when using one of its methods (`changePlayer` in this case), like this:

```
$: game = useStore().changePlayer(player);
```

Now I would like to get the type from `player` automagically.

I think this is doable but I don't wanna destroy the store everytime `player` changes.

How to do this? **Is there a way?**

---

Similar, but not related: [TypeScript - How do you infer a class generic type from a method's parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916018/typescript-how-do-you-infer-a-class-generic-type-from-a-methods-parameter)

Answer (score 2):

you could create a generic typescript `Store<T>` class and add a static method to create a new store using your value:

```js
export class Store<T> {
  
  constructor(value: T){
    // your logic (svelte store creation)
  }

  static create(value: T): Store<T> {
    return new Store(value);
  }
}

// a possible usage could be:
const player = Store.create(player);
```

I hope it helps!